# Visual flow Lookup from contact page

Tags: visual-workflow

I am new to Visual workflow i create a javascript button in contact page which on click redirects to a flow which should dynamically pull that contact information from contact page and display in the visual flow  the fields which i want to display is contact name,email id, account name can someone help on this issue

Comment: If you use the resources like the Visual Flow workbook which can be found on the SF Developer forum here - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Visual_Workflow  This is a simple operation. Stack Exchange is really for dealing with problems you encounter not showing simple tutorials that are already covered by Salesforce on trailhead - https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/business_process_automation

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Flow the Contact Record ID into a flow variable with the Input/Output type set to Input,e.g. varContactID, then use a Fast Lookup on Contact to retrieve the fields into an sObject variable. Make sure that you select all the fields that you require into the sObject variable or else the flow will fail with an error message when you try and surface the selected fields. To display the account name you will have to do another lookup as the Account reference from the Contact will be the record Id not the name.

[image: Fast Lookup]

Then you can surface the fields from the sObject variable on the Screen objects within the Flow as either default values on a screen field or into display text area in the Screen object.

[image: Default value]